# SQL 2005/2008 create sequence diagram of stored procedure and db interaction

Tags: sql-server, callstack, sequence-diagram

We have a very complex set of stored procedures that have been migrated over from Oracle in to SQL 2005.  At one time, I heard there was a solution where sequence diagrams could be created from either watching a stack trace in VS or by the SQL profiler.  I've searched long and hard and have found may tools that will create sequence diagrams of your code, but not the DB interaction.  Is anybody aware of a set of tools that maybe able to help me out.

I can stand up many different environments including SQL 2005, SQL 2005, VS 2005, VS 2008.

Comment: pencil and paper, and a lot of code to read...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any, but you could add a call-log table with a timestamp and sp/function name, and have each sp & function log its activity.